# Run cypress test without using the GUI

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

Is it possible to run a Cypress test without using the GUI where you can choose the test file. Currently I open it this way:

I type in CMD: `node_modules/.bin/cypress open` and then the GUI pops up where I can choose my test.

Is there a command which avoids that the GUI is popping up and what is the command?

Answer (score 2):

You can run with command line in headed like this:

```
node_modules\\.bin\\cypress run --headed
```

this will run the tests by default in Electron browser.

And headless:

```
node_modules\\.bin\\cypress run
```

Comment: And what if I only want to run one test file

Comment: same command, just add --spec "--spec "cypress/integration/examples/nameofTest.js"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is `cypress run`. It is all described in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands).

To run a specific file, you need to pass `--spec` argument, like this:

```
node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/nameOfTheTest.js"
```

Comment: If i use this I get UnauthorizedAccess